# Elasticsearch 1.3.2 java api setScript throws exception on execution

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch java api version 1.3.2, the "setScript()" method does not work by default, like the examples given in Elasticsearch home site. I tried the following, but it threw an exception on execution.

```
UpdateResponse ur = null;
Map par = new HashMap();
par.put("nsite", "newfield");
par.put("docid", "56783");
ur = client.prepareUpdate(index, type, id)
     .setScriptParams(par)
     .setScript("ctx._source.sites.nsite=docid",ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
     .execute().actionGet();                
System.out.println("updated for "+site);
```

(Note:- in latest version, Elasticsearch requires two params for "setScript" method)
.setScript("ctx._source.sites.nsite=docid") => wrong method signature, script type is mandatory param now.

On running this i got the "Execution exception" as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:173)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:310)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2132)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:537)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.readObject(InetSocketAddress.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1872)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1894)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1894)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:171)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the script language by default is not groovy for some reason in newer versions of es. Need to provide that too explicitly. SO, on providing the script language it worked now. (Note:- **setScriptLang("groovy")** is the required param if groovy is your choice of script in es).

```
UpdateResponse ur = null;
Map par = new HashMap();
par.put("nsite", "newfield");
par.put("docid", "56783");
ur = client.prepareUpdate(index, type, id)
     .setScriptLang("groovy")
     .setScriptParams(par)
     .setScript("ctx._source.sites.nsite=docid",ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
     .execute().actionGet();                
System.out.println("updated for "+site);
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not clearly mentioned in the elastic search tutorial or their website.